# Perl script displayed as plain text in linux mint?

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

i did install libapache2-mod-perl2 to run perl files as CGI through apache
each time i tried to navigate the perl file browser display it as a plain text .

```
###Start###
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "Hello there";
###End###
```

and this the Virtual Host File

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    ServerName  perl.dev
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/test>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/test/cgi-bin
    <Directory "/var/www/test/cgi-bin">
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
        Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride none
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

when i tried to run the script using the terminal it just work fine but through browser it never show the right output
Thank you

Comment: Are you actually accessing this through your web server (over HTTP), or are you trying to access it from the filesystem (with a file:// URL)?

Comment: im trying to access over HTTP not from a file system

Comment: And in which directory is your test script located? And how did you name it?

Comment: /var/www/test/cgi-bin

Comment: Are `###Start###` and `###End###` part of your file? `#!/usr/bin/perl` line *must* be on the first line.

Comment: @Borodin yes they are but even after removing them it still showing the code as plain text in chrome and it send me to download the file when navigate the link through Firefox

Comment: @Dr.Neo: And as innaM asked, what is the name of your Perl file?

Answer (score 0):

You mention "libapache2-mod-perl2" so you are using mod_perl.

For mod_perl you have to use SetHandler perl-script.

I make a difference between regular cgi and mod-perl. This is how I configure mod-perl in apache2:

```
ScriptAlias /perl-bin/ /usr/lib/perl-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/perl-bin">
       AllowOverride None
       Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

       SetHandler perl-script
       PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
       PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
       #Order allow,deny
       #Allow from all
       Require ip 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.0/16
</Directory>
```